# Getting the Facebook like/share count for a given URL with Graph API v2.2 and Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

In Graph API v1.0 I did this in Javascript in order to retrive a page shares count, with jQuery in the specific example below:

```
var url = 'http://example.org/some/article/to/get/shares/or/likes/';
jQuery.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/"+escape(url)+"?callback=?", function(json) {
    if( "shares" in json && 0 != json.shares ) {
        $this.append('<span class="facebook-share-counter">'+json.shares+'</span>');
    }
} );
```

With Graph API v2.2 it seems, after doing some test with [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and according to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/index-api/v2.2), that an acces token is required in order to make a request to the index API.

Any idea how to convert the code above for Graph API v2.2?

Thank you.